# Ajax not working inside iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, iteration

I have a `AtpRank` model containing the first 100 Atp tennis players. 
My goal is to create in the view a table listing all tennis players and their attributes, along with a button for each player useful for the user to choose a list of tennis players. The `home.html.erb` code is below:

```
<% @atp_ranks.each do |tennis_player| %>
  <tr id="tennist-<%= tennis_player.ranking %>">
    <td class="atpranking"> <%= tennis_player.ranking %> </td>
    <td class="atpname"> <%= tennis_player.name %> </td>
    <td class="atppoints"> <%= tennis_player.points %> </td>
    <% unless Time.now.month == 12 %>
      <td>
        <div id="atpenlist_form">
          <% if current_user.atpenlisted?(tennis_player) %>
            <%= form_for(current_user.atp_selections.find_by(atp_rank_id: tennis_player.id),
                                                 html: { method: :delete }, remote: true) do |f| %>
              <%= f.submit "Dump", class: "btn btn-warning btn-sm" %>
            <% end %>
          <% else %>
            <%= form_for(current_user.atp_selections.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
              <div><%= hidden_field_tag :atp_id, tennis_player.id %></div>
              <%= f.submit "Choose", class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, the form uses Ajax having set `remote: true` in the `form_for` helper.
Requests are handled by the `atp_selections` controller. Below is an extract of the create action of this controller:

```
    current_user.atpenlist(tennist)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_url }
      format.js
    end
```

The `destroy` action uses the `atpdiscard` method instead of the `atpenlist` method. 
In app/views/atp_selections I created the `create.js.erb` and `destroy.js.erb` files. 
 
Below is the `app/views/atp_selections/create.js.erb` file:

```
$("#atpenlist_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/atpdiscard')) %>");
$("#atp_count").html('<%= current_user.atp_ranks.count %>');
```

Each of the `app/view/users/_atpenlist.html.erb` and `app/view/users/_atpdiscard.html.erb` partials contain the respective form (the same exact part of the code above starting with `form_for`).

I have to say that in the original code for the home page I did not explicitly included the entire code for the forms, but I just rendered the partials. This did not work: rails warned me that it could not find the variable or method `tennis_player` used in the iteration, for some reason to me unknown. So I had to renounce to render the partials and decided to include the entire code.

The issue is now that Ajax does not work: I have to refresh the page to see the results of submitting the form. I checked my code and could not find errors or explanation for this.

Comment: tennis_player is a local variable for you home.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tennis_player` is a local variable for you home.html.erb .

 So you need to pass it in js.erb like

```
$("#atpenlist_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/atpdiscard'), locals: {tennis_player: your_tennis_player_object}) %>");
```

Set the tennis player object in your controller & use that in above js.erb

Comment: tennis_player is the variable of the iteration. The object of the iteration is @atp_ranks = AtpRank.limit(100) which is set in the controller for the home page (that I called static_pages controller). What am I supposed to use inside the js.erb as 'my_tennis_player_object'? locals: {tennis_player: @atp_ranks} does not work.